# How do i make a div responsive when its got relative positioning with left and right attributes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, responsive

I am trying to make this responsive so when you scale it down it will move along with the nav bar like a responsive website. i am using bootstrap however I want to keep the div in the center of the website and not filling the whole width.

```
<div class="main-body">
    <div class="MainImage">
        <img src="shirini1.jpg"  height="700">
    </div>
    <div class="RedBar">       
        <p id="Welcome">Welcome to my Website</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

and css

```
.main-body{
position: relative;
left: 370px;
width: 60%;
display: inline-block;
}

.main-body,img{ 
position: relative;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
}

.RedBar{
height:50px;
background-color:#ff4c55;

}

#Welcome{
color: white;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
top: 10px;
font-size: 24px
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `margin: 0 auto; display:block;` to `.main-body` and remove `left: 370px` to make this always in center.